# Feasibility of converting long body carriers into stationary field hospitals

Tags: airliner

Considering the current pandemic crisis, and the fact that and there are thousands of grounded planes that can be put to other uses, I come with a somewhat dumb question.

Is it possible to remove seats in a long-body passenger carrier to, instead of flying with two hundred cramped passengers, make it spacely enough to carry forty or fifty narrow beds and a small staff to take care of them, while stationary on the ground?

Is it feasible, from an economic viewpoint, to pay air companies for this, in comparison to actually building tents or renting buildings in a big town like New York or San Francisco?

**EDIT**

Yeah, I mean stationary planes, with external APU to power up the air conditioning and lights and rampies to take the waste away and constantly fill it with water.

Comment: Probably simpler and no reason not to work is to convert the airport passenger area into hospital.

Comment: Actually, train cars and ships are more suitable for these kind of tasks and has been done. Grounding an airplane is kind of expensive, compared with trains and ships.

Comment: I like your invention of the new word "spacely"

Comment: Better  to use military ships as they are all infected anyway or soon will be, and they are bigger than airliners.

Comment: Hotels, convention centers, schools, and other buildings would be far better choice.  No special benefits from using airplanes, and I could see a lot of downsides...

Comment: There's no way you're going to fit 50 beds, dividers, and all the equipment required in a jet, then power it all on top of that.

Comment: short answer: yes it is feasible as it is done for medical evacuation but not needed as other transformations are cheaper and more effective (more space, easier to get in and out of a building than a plane, ...)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very opinion based question that will garner many opinion based answers. Not the type of type of fact based question that is the purpose of this site.

The pros of this concept would be:

1. Provide revenue for the airline.
2. Provide space for the ill.

The cons of this concept would be:

1. Aircraft get awfully hot or cold when not being powered.
2. There are no adequate facilities for long term waste and hygiene.
3. The air in an unpowered aircraft would be awfully stagnant. That is not good for the health of the recovering, nor that of the medical personnel.
4. If worse came to worse, there are a lot of unoccupied buildings that can be rented at the same or less cost than an airplane. They would already have the infrastructure for power and plumbing.
5. The Army and Army National Guard already have most of the tents and other housing facilities bought, paid for, and in storage for these types of emergencies.
6. Even for a pilot, timeframe for recovery, stuck in a fuselage, with that many other people would be claustrophobic. Think of how it feels if you are under a stay-at-home sequester order, now. Now, multiply that by ten.
7. Costly decontamination post-pandemic.
8. Running an engine or APU 24/7 would be cost prohibitive.
9. Having lived in a space with fifty other guys for an extended period of time, even with bunk beds, I can tell you that it would require more space than you might think. 1000 square feet (100 m^2) would be my estimate of the bare minimum without dining nor food preparation facilities, and minimal toileting facilities. That would be 20 square feet per person. That is less space than a king sized bed per couple for the entire living space.
10. Cruise ships and hotels would be a more feasible option.

Comment: I like cruise ships and hotel options, using planes like that can be reduced to a very peculiar situation, if any.